# Use string matching to de-dupe results of query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the format:

```
Id     | Loc |
-------|-----|
789-A  | 4   |
123    | 1   |
123-BZ | 1   |
123-CG | 2   |
456    | 2   |
456    | 3   |
789    | 4   |
```

I want to exclude certain rows from the result of query based on whether a duplicate exists. In this case, though, the definition of a duplicate row is pretty complex:

If **any** row returned by the query (let's refer to this hypothetical row as `ThisRow`) has a counterpart row **also contained within the query results** where `Loc` is identical to `ThisRow.Loc` AND `Id` is of the form `<ThisRow.Id>-<an alphanumeric suffix>` then `ThisRow` should be considered a duplicate and excluded from the query results.

For example, using the table above, `SELECT * FROM table` should return the results set below:

```
Id     | Loc |
-------|-----|
789-A  | 4   |
123-BZ | 1   |
123-CG | 2   |
456    | 2   |
456    | 3   |
```

I understand how to write the string matching conditional:

```
ThisRow.Id REGEXP '^PossibleDuplicateRow.Id-[A-Za-z0-9]*'
```

and the straight comparison of `Loc`:

```
ThisRow.Loc = PossibleDuplicateRow.Loc
```

What I don't understand is how to form these conditionals into a (self-referential?) query.

Comment: Are numeric part in id field always 3 digits? by the way weird db, pls re-design it better!

Comment: what have you tried so far? Please show us your query so that we can help you.

Comment: @nawfal: No, the values in `Id` are vary heavily, I've just simplified the requirement for the purposes of this question. As far as the database goes, I'm working with what I've been given, I'm afraid :)

Comment: @FahimParkar: at the moment I'm just returning all the results then iterating over them in php, then identifying and excluding the duplicates using further sql queries. While this does work, it's much more inefficient and makes it difficult to get metrics like the total number of valid results or to `limit` into a set number of rows per page. I have no idea how to form the query, hence why I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM myTable t2
    WHERE t2.Loc = t1.Loc
    AND t2.Id LIKE CONCAT(t1.Id, '-%')
)
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06758/1)

Or, the same query using an anti-join (which should be a little faster):

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable t2 
    ON t2.Loc = t1.Loc
    AND t2.Id LIKE CONCAT(t1.Id, '-%')
WHERE t2.Id IS NULL
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06758/2)

Comment: The first where condition isnt required in the first query

Comment: @nawfal Which where condition?

Comment: `WHERE t2.Loc = t1.Loc` in the first query. and possibly in 2nd query too :)

Comment: He just needs to check if a specific value exist in one column (id), not related to loc at all.

Comment: @nawfal From the question: "where `Loc` is identical to `ThisRow.Loc` AND `Id` is...". Am I misinterpreting this?

Comment: @lc: cheers for this, I've seen a similar form while googling for an answer, but didn't understand the significance of `t1` and `t2`. From the context I assume that they're ways of assigning a query-able name to a set of results? As you might have guessed, the example table I gave above is a bit of a simplification of my actual data, but I think I can see how to implement your solution with the real table. I'll give it a go and get back to you :)

Comment: @lc. Oh yes I missed it, apologies :)

Comment: @sjwarner Yes, it's a table alias. Since you have the same table name twice in the query this is required to disambiguate the two. Note I have left out the optional `AS` keyword in the the syntax `FROM <tablename> [[AS] <alias>]`.

Answer (score 0):

In the example data you give, there are no examples of duplicate locs *not* being on duplicate rows.  For example, you don't have a row "123-AZ, 1", where the prefix row "123, 1" would conflict with two rows.

If this is a real characteristic of the data, then you can eliminate dups without a self join, by using aggregation:

```
select max(id), loc
from t
group by (case when locate(id, '-') = 0 then id
               else left(id, locate(id, '-') - 1)
          end), loc
```

I offer this because an aggregation should be much faster than a non-equijoin.

Comment: This seems to return *only* the duplicate rows, plus any rows which look like them - I've updated Ic's fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d931/29